# How to fill a portion of an SKShapeNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I have a SKShapeNode which is a square. I want to fill half of it in yellow and the other half leave clear. How would I do this?

Comment: You cannot do this with a single shape node. I'd suggest attaching two child shape nodes, one for each color.

Comment: Why use an SKShapeNode, just use an SKSpriteNode with a texture of half and half